# How can I overcome Nokogiri issue when dockerizing a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I'm trying to use docker for my rails app. This is the setup I have: `ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [arm64-darwin22, Rails 7.0.4.3`

I have created a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.0.0

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And a docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  redis:
    image: redis
    command: redis-server
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL_CACHING=redis://redis:6379/0
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_USERNAME=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=password

volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
```

I'm using postgresql database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_HOST") %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_USERNAME") %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_PASSWORD") %>
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
```

I then proceed with the following commands:

1. `docker-compose build`
2. `docker-compose up`

But I get the following error after the docker-compose up:

```
my_rails_app-web-1    | ERROR: It looks like you're trying to use Nokogiri as a precompiled native gem on a system
my_rails_app-web-1    |        with an unsupported version of glibc.
my_rails_app-web-1    | 
my_rails_app-web-1    |   /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /usr/local/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.14.4-aarch64-linux/lib/nokogiri/3.0/nokogiri.so) - /usr/local/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.14.4-aarch64-linux/lib/nokogiri/3.0/nokogiri.so
my_rails_app-web-1    | 
my_rails_app-web-1    |   If that's the case, then please install Nokogiri via the `ruby` platform gem:
my_rails_app-web-1    |       gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby
my_rails_app-web-1    |   or:
my_rails_app-web-1    |       bundle config set force_ruby_platform true
my_rails_app-web-1    | 
my_rails_app-web-1    |   Please visit https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for more help.
```

I tried this: `gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby` and this `bundle config set force_ruby_platform true.` But the same error appears!

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try and avoid trailing "dot zero" versions of Ruby if you can. 3.0.0 had bugs that were fixed in later patches, and the current version of 3.0 is now 3.0.6. Even better, try and use 3.1 or 3.2 if you can to better future-proof your container.

Comment: Are you deploying on ARM or x86_64?

Comment: Yes, `3.0.0` is fairly old. Can you try on `3.0.6` or better yet `ruby:3.2.2`?

Comment: Additionally you could be more specific as to how to build `nokogiri` within your container; you could take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243794/cant-install-nokogiri-with-bundle-when-build-docker-container-in-archlinux) to have an idea, though it's a bit old.

Comment: @tadman, Yes I am deploying on ARM!

Comment: Plus, I am already on the latest version: `rvm install ruby --latest Already installed ruby 3.0.0. To reinstall use: rvm reinstall ruby-3.0.0`